# Why does strtok return the wrong number of tokens?

Tags: c

I've been solving an Advent of Code problem in C, and I've hit something I don't understand. My C is very rusty, and I know this isn't a great example of C code. I have stripped the program down to the smallest section that demonstrates the behaviour that confuses me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int ae_load_file_to_memory(const char *filename, char **result)
{
    int size = 0;
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        *result = NULL;
        return -1; 
    }
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    *result = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1));
    if (size != fread(*result, sizeof(char), size, f))
    {
        free(*result);
        return -2; 
    }
    fclose(f);
    (*result)[size] = 0;
    return size;
}

int main(void)
{
    const char delim = '\n';
    int fill_index = 0;
    char *token = NULL;
    char *content = NULL;

    ae_load_file_to_memory("input.txt", &content);

    token = strtok(content, &delim);

    while (token != NULL)
    {
        fill_index++;
        token = strtok(NULL, &delim);
    }
    printf("Fill index %d\n", fill_index);
}
```

This code reads a file from disk, and then splits it into tokens using the newline as the delimiter. The final `printf` returns the correct number of tokens, 1044.

However, if I change the start of the `main` method to move the declaration of `fill_index`:

```
int main(void)
{
    int fill_index = 0;
    const char delim = '\n';
```

...now `strtok` returns 1050 tokens, which is wrong. That's the only difference between the two files. I'm running on Mac OS X Sierra, `gcc --version` reports that its `Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)`.

I'm sure I'm stomping on memory somewhere, and the first version only works by coincidence. However, I've got no idea why moving that declaration makes such a difference. Can anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: The second argument to [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) is a ***null-terminated** byte string*. Not a pointer to a single character.

Comment: Please make sure all compiler warnings are enabled, and read them. This should not compile cleanly at all.

Comment: @unwind `gcc -Wall` compiled cleanly.

Comment: @someprogrammerdude and @coderredoc were right. Fixing the second parameter solved the problem. I guess the first posted version worked because `fill_index` was stored after `delim` in memory, so it acted as a null-terminator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't use the `delim` properly. It would be  `const char delim[] = "\n";` (Null terminated char array not a single character).

Earlier you were invoking undefined behavior by passing the wrong parameter.

From standard  §7.24.5.8

```
char *strtok(char * restrict s1,const char * restrict s2);
```

And some example

```
static char str[] = "?a???b,,,#c";
         char *t;
         t   =   strtok(str, "?");         //   t   points to the token "a"
         t   =   strtok(NULL, ",");        //   t   points to the token "??b"
         t   =   strtok(NULL, "#,");       //   t   points to the token "c"
         t   =   strtok(NULL, "?");        //   t   is a null pointer
```